# How to execute a job from queue?

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue

I am using Laravel Queue with the database driver to delay some tasks.

However, I can't run the designed worker because of reasons. lnstead I decided to use the scheduler to call my own worker every 5 minutes.

However, I can't really understand how to implement the worker and I can't fully get my head aroujd the original code myself. I would like to retrieve the jobs that are due from the database and run them. How to do that?

Is there some generic model for jobs that can load them correctly like `DatabaseJob::whereDate(......)->get()`?

Do I have to load something (payload?) for the jobs or will it happen automatically? Which methods do I need to execute the job? ´handle()´? ´fire()´? Or something else?

Comment: What kind of scheduler are you using ? eg. crond or SheduledTasks (windows) or ...

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [`WorkCommand`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php). In theory, you should be able to use the same code in your cronjob. But I would definitely not advise you to do so. If you still do, make sure you handle the concurrency of cronjobs properly.

Comment: @simonecosci I have cron that runs Laravel's own task scheduler.

Comment: @Namoshek I am looking how to launch the jobs from within the Laravel. And I will only run this every five minutes so concurency shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Of course concurrency will be a problem, sooner or later. If your queue contains more jobs (or jobs taking longer) than you can process in five minutes, you will receive overlapping queue workers. An alternative could be to start a new worker within your scheduled jobs only if none is running yet. But anyway, using a common webhost is not how you should run laravel and you will run into other issues as well. A proper server is what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run artisan commands from your code by using the `call()` method on the Artisan facade. For example, this will process all ready jobs from the default queue and exit when it's done:

`Artisan::call('queue:work', ['--stop-when-empty' => true])`

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands):

> Sometimes you may wish to execute an Artisan command outside of the
>   CLI. For example, you may wish to fire an Artisan command from a route
>   or controller. You may use the `call` method on the Artisan facade to
>   accomplish this. The `call` method accepts either the command's name or
>   class as the first argument, and an array of command parameters as the
>   second argument. The exit code will be returned:
>
> ```
> Route::get('/foo', function () {
>     $exitCode = Artisan::call('email:send', [
>         'user' => 1, '--queue' => 'default'
>     ]);
>
>     // });
> ```

The same syntax would work for [scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling):

`$schedule->command('queue:work', [...])->everyFiveMinutes();`

As others have pointed out, running the worker *inside* `schedule:run` may lead to undesired behavior such as skipped scheduled tasks.

For your questions on how dispatching and running queued jobs works, this is the place to start: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues

Comment: Cool, thanks! I didn't know about the `--stop-when-empty` option as I am working in 5.6, but it does pretty much what I needed. I just had to extend the `WorkCommand` and `Worker` classes with my own and override a couple of methods to implement the stopping as in 5.7.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup horizon for queue job monitoring reference link:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/horizon

Or Run pre Artisan cmd

`php artisan queue:listen database --queue=high`

Comment: I would like to implement some of what `queue:listen` does in my own code that would be run by Laravels scheduler. I can't execute my own php commands on the prod server but the scheudduler is set up and running there

Comment: If you are not able to run command on prod server so you need to setup horizon that will be really helpful for you.